# What version of PHP is Symfony using?

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework, php-5.3, php-5.4

I have been struggling with this for a few hours now. I am running CentOS 6.6. A few hours ago I was having issues with a Symfony project that required PHP 5.4+ because of some libraries required. So I installed version 5.4 and I used to have PHP 5.3.3.

PHP 5.4 allows some new features. Such as array shorthand declaration and binary data strings. Like this:

```
//array shorthand declaration
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]; //PHP +5.4

$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4); //PHP 5.3.3

//binary data strings
0b001 //PHP +5.4
```

This is on the official documentation so here's a link to the source: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

However when executing those scripts I am getting errors as if I was not running PHP 5.4 for example I would get this one:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /vendor/wisembly/elephant.io/src/Engine/AbstractSocketIO.php on line 44
```

And the line of code would be:

```
//does not work
$data = [$event, $args]; //PHP 5.4 syntax

//it works
$data = array($event, $args); //PHP 5.3.3 syntax
```

This is the output of running php -v on the terminal

```
PHP 5.4.43 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2015 12:08:50)  
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group  
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

So based on this output I know I am running PHP version 5.4, the only thing that occurs to me is that somehow there is a configuration error somewhere and it is still using PHP 5.3.

So my question is how do I know what version of PHP is Symfony using? Thanks.

Comment: run `phpinfo()` on one of your pages and see what that gives you. its possible for you to have one version of php for the cli and one running from apache

Comment: Just to "confirm" that it isn't a Symfony configuration, why don't you write a simple php with an array and try to execute it?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html  says 5.3.9

Answer (score 4):

When you run `php -v`, it show you the CLI's php version. Not the php version used for your script (run by your webserver).

You have multiple solutions to get the version used by your webserver.

**Example with the function [`phpinfo();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) in a .php page.**

```
<?php
    phpinfo(); // Outputs information about PHP's configuration
```

**Example directly from the command line (show you the same information displayed with an `phpinfo()`)**

```
php -i
```

Comment: Thanks, but strangely it says PHP Version => 5.4.43

Comment: Which version did you tried (`phpinfo()` or `php -i`) ?

Comment: Can you try to execute the `phpinfo();` in a php page ? please

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar. Chances are that Apache is still pointing at another version of PHP on the machine. Checkout `phpinfo();` to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `symfony console about`, which displays the PHP version near the end:

```
E:\webfolder>symfony console about
 -------------------- ---------------------------------
  Symfony
 -------------------- ---------------------------------
  Version              5.1.2
  Long-Term Support    No
  End of maintenance   01/2021
  End of life          01/2021
 -------------------- ---------------------------------
  Kernel
 -------------------- ---------------------------------
  Type                 App\Kernel
  Environment          dev
  Debug                true
  Charset              UTF-8
  Cache directory      ./var/cache/dev (726 KiB)
  Log directory        ./var/log (0 B)
 -------------------- ---------------------------------
  PHP
 -------------------- ---------------------------------
  Version              7.4.0
  Architecture         64 bits
  Intl locale          fr_FR
  Timezone             UTC (2020-07-21T20:20:32+00:00)
  OPcache              false
  APCu                 false
  Xdebug               false
 -------------------- ---------------------------------
```